# Domain IP address for www and non-www for Canonical URL

Tags: dns, seo, subdomain

To handle Canonical URL is it best practice to do a 301 redirect or better to have the same IP Address for both www and non www domain?

For example:

Canonical URL/domain wanted is http://example.com

```
Domain           | A Record
------------------------------------
example.com      | 192.0.2.34
www.example.com  | 192.0.2.34
```

I understand people may have a CNAME record for www (alias, given that CNAME is called Canonical Name); unsure if this is best practice compared to using the same IP address.

Or is this better.

```
Domain           | A Record
------------------------------------
example.com     | 192.0.2.34
*  www.example.com 301 redirect to example.com
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The mechanisms you describe (`A` and `CNAME` records vs. `301` redirects) are part of two different protocols (DNS and HTTP). `A` and `CNAME` records have nothing to do with which site your HTTP server serves for different requests.

Let's look at two different DNS configurations:

#### Configuration 1 (CNAME record)

```
Host             | Type  | Data
-----------------+-------+-------------
example.com      | A     | 192.0.2.34
www.example.com  | CNAME | example.com
```

- `nslookup example.com` resolves to `192.0.2.34`
- `nslookup www.example.com` resolves to `192.0.2.34`

#### Configuration 2 (A records)

```
Host             | Type  | Data
-----------------+-------+-------------
example.com      | A     | 192.0.2.34
www.example.com  | A     | 192.0.2.34
```

- `nslookup example.com` resolves to `192.0.2.34`
- `nslookup www.example.com` resolves to `192.0.2.34`

In both cases your canonical domain and your `www` subdomain resolve to `192.0.2.34`. However, the only thing your HTTP server will recognize is that it receives requests for both `example.com` and `www.example.com` on the same IP address. But it doesn't know whether you used `A` or `CNAME` records for that.

### TL;DR

You have to use HTTP 301 redirects to enforce the canonical `example.com` in HTTP requests. But that has nothing to do with your DNS configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. HTTP redirect or an A record to the server that will complete the redirect will sort out canonical url issues. You are a kind person, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Nice explanation. But I have one question. how to force to use www instead canonical? For one of my domain it serves only canonical domain even though I visit www. it redirects to canonical url. Any idea?

Comment: @SD The redirects are caused by your webserver. Check your webserver configuration whether there are any redirects from the `www` domain to your canonical domain and remove them if you don't want that.

Comment: @PoByBolek do you mean I should check apache config for this?

Comment: @SD yes, definitely

Comment: @PoByBolek I just checked apache.conf, conf-enabled/* and also sites-enabled/000-default.conf file. I didn't find anything suspicious. That may be because I wasn't sure what I was looking for. Will you please help me here?

Comment: @PoByBolek I am done. All settings were correct but the url coming from db. Silly me. Anyway, thanks for you help here.

Comment: wrong, it will still show as www.mydomain.com. I don't get how is that an accepted answer. The only solution here is by Chetabahana

Comment: @Toolkit care to elaborate on that? From my understanding, Chetabahana's answer solves the problem by having clients send their first HTTP request for `www.mydomain.com` to redirect.center's servers, which then do an HTTP 301  redirect to `mydomain.com`. So you'd have to rely on someone else's infrastructure to achieve something that you could easily configure yourself.

Comment: @PoByBolek there is no way to redirect using CNAME. If the OP wants `Canonical URL/domain wanted is http://mydomain.cоm` then there is only one way to do a redirect. Otherwise you will end up displaying website on `http://mydomain.cоm` and `http://www.mydomain.cоm`

Comment: @Toolkit that's basically what I am saying, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

You may try [redirect.center](http://redirect.center). Its redirects domains using DNS only.
So it will fulfill your DNS configurations:

```
Domain           | A Record
------------------------------------
example.com      | 192.0.2.34
*  www.example.com 301 redirect to example.com
```

set your DNS record to:

> CNAME  | www  | example.com.opts-https.redirect.center

Note:
The `.opts-https.` parameter redirect to `https` domain
If you use only `http` domain then use `.opts-uri.`

Comment: this is a solution i was looking for all my life :) thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In DNS the canonical name record is pointing to the "one true DNS entry". The end result is that DNSName1 has the same IP address as DNSName2.

Comprehension is complicated by the fact that the CNAME is not the canonical name. The CName Record points to the canonical name. (The canonical name is the A record).

Canonical link:
For search engines the canonical link in the html header of a page specifies the "one true page". You can get to multiple pages but you use the canonical link to tell the search engine that this page is the same as the other page. Doing this makes the search engine happy that you are not gaming the system by pretending to provide more content where it is only duplication. It only indexes it once.

301 (http) redirects:
For search engines this says that page x is now replaced by page y and all the search ranking can be transferred to page y. If it is a "cosmetic" domain-name-standardisation it also tells the search engine to only index one page and is again a way to show that you're not trying to trick the search engine.