# DNS Records Redirect www to non-www

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, server

I'm using [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/) Domains and [Vultr](https://www.vultr.com) Hosting.

I'm trying to redirect DNS www to non-www.

www.example.com to example.com

---

I contacted Vultr and asked how to do this with their DNS Manager, they said they would not help as it is self-managed. So I contacted Namecheap, they said they would not help becuase they don't have access to Vultr's DNS Manager, would not tell me if the records I showed them are correct, and I would need to contact Vultr. So I am in an endless support loop.

---

**Vultr DNS Manager**

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19592764/6806643) on how to set up a CNAME to redirect to non-www.

```
Type   | Name | Data         | Seconds
--------------------------------------
A      |      | ipv4 address | 300
AAAA   |      | ipv6 address | 300
CNAME  | .    | example.com  | 300
CNAME  | www  | example.com  | 300
```

After waiting all night for it to propgate, the www can still be visited and does not redirect.

It does not allow me to make another `A` record, only `CNAME`. It says:

```
Unable to add record: A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.
```

---

**NGINX**

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-centos-7#option-1-redirect-www-to-non-www) and tried redirecting it with sites-available config. Http and Https work, but www does not redirect to non-www.

```
server {
    # Redirect http to https
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    # Redirect www to non-www
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.key;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    server_name example.com;
    ...
```

Comment: What is "www.example.com" serving for you?

Comment: @SteveHarris It serves the website as normal, the same as non-www.

Comment: What happens if you remove the "." (dot) entry from your DNS manager?

Comment: @AllenLuce It was put there automatically by Vultr when I added the domain. If I edit it, it turns into a star *. I'm not sure I should remove it.

Comment: A dot typically means "this domain." If that's true for you, it means you've got a CNAME on the domain level (i.e. a CNAME for example.com). Since you've already got A/AAAA records on the domain, this leads to an invalid configuration. What do you get when you `dig example.com any` (but with your domain)?

Comment: @AllenLuce It says "connection timed out; no servers could be reached".

Comment: @RichardSmith's answer looks pretty good.  Your config has the default server listening on 443 but your redirect config is not.  It doesn't look like the redirect would ever get served (or reached since default is probably port 80).   Try the posted answer from Mr. Smith.

Comment: I think @RichardSmith has part of the answer (you do need to do the www-to-non redirect via https). Remove the dot record and you should have the whole thing solved.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

DNS cannot redirect your www site to non-www. The only purpose of DNS is to point both www and non-www to your server's IP address using `A`, `AAAA` or `CNAME` records (it makes little difference). The `nginx` configuration is responsible for performing the redirect from www to non-www.

Your second server block is intended to redirect from www to non-www, but currently only handles `http` connections (on port 80).

You can move the default server and use that to redirect everything to the intended domain name. For example:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.key;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ...
}
```

Assuming that you have a common certificate for both the www and non-www domain names, you can move the `ssl_` directives into the outer block and allow them to be inherited into both server blocks (as shown above).

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for more.

Comment: It's working. I removed CNAME and used 2 A Records for @ and www. I reconfigured NGINX sites-available to use your layout. It now redirects http:// www .example.com to https:// example.com.

Comment: Perfect Solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can direct www to non-www by adding a **new** server block to your nginx configuration file.

Step 1: Add the following server block to your nginx configuration file.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Step 2: Restart nginx.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```