# How to redirect typed in url https://www.example.com to example.com with NGINX

Tags: nginx

Whenever an URL is typed in with `https://www.example.com`, what is the way to redirect to `example.com` at NGINX?

Currently, I have NGINX block that redirects to example.com

```
server {      
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

But this will do no good, if the URL is *typed* in as `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Maybe something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www/43089681#43089681)?

Comment: Yeah, my current redirection at the server is working fine. But, when the full url is "typed" in. It all fails.