# NGINX redirect http to https and www. to non-www

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-redirect

I finally got my certificates made with Let's Encrypt working.
I am struggling with nginx though. I've been using this as a revers proxy, and I found it quite good.
Now my site can be accessed with https://example.net , but I'd like it if http://www.example.net and https://www.example.net would be redirected to https://example.net .
But my current configuration doesn't work.

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name example.net;
   return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.example.net;
   rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.net/$1 permanent;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  example.net;

    ssl_certificate /home/shiro/LE-Cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/shiro/LE-Cert.key;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://10.0.0.3:443;
    }
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name www.example.net;
   rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.net/$1 permanent;
}
```

How would I go about setting something like this up?
Nginx is running on ubuntu if it matters.

EDIT: OH. MY. GOD.
I feel so stupid right now..
I found the problem, fixed it, and it was that when I set up thet acme package on pfSense I had to forward http to pfsense:8082. Then I didn't disable it and didn't enable the one for that forwards to nginx..

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www/43089681#43089681)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH. MY. GOD.
I feel so stupid right now..
I found the problem, fixed it, and it was that when I set up thet acme package on pfSense I had to forward http to pfsense:8082. Then I didn't disable it and didn't enable the one for that forwards to nginx..