# CNAME and redirect to non-www

Tags: redirect, dns, cname

I searched the web and I found out that the proper way to redirect www to non-www is to add a CNAME record that points to the non-www domain name, and then do the redirect in the server as well.

But I don't understand what should I put as "name".

Is it `www.example.com` or just `www` ?

I noticed that both work, but in the codes I found I saw that people use just `www`.

The problem is that if I use `www` then what will happen if I have multiple subdomains, like `www.mysubdomain1.example.com`, `www.mysubdomain2.example.com` ?

Comment: It really depends on your DNS server's user interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43089681/1135424

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, `www` is also a subdomain to the TLD `example.com`

In general you don't require to use multi-level subdomains eg. `www.subdomain.example.com` If even if you put just `www` it won't create multi-level subdomains, For creating multilevel subdomains you would require to enter - `www.subdomain` in the CNAME name field.

Generally most of the DNS providers work by entring the subdomain string eg. `www` or `subdomain`.