# https://[ip address] to domain redirect nginx

Tags: nginx, url, redirect, https, ip

I am using nginx and I figured out how to redirect http://[IP address] to my domain but I can't get https to work. I've tried:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name 31.220.108.250;

    return 301 https://mosachi.ga$request_uri;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: That `server` block is incomplete and may be causing errors. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and ensure that the new `server` block appears without any errors. But for a simple solution to redirect everything to your domain name, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www/43089681#43089681).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to redirect all different urls like:

- http://example.com,
- https://something.example.com
- https://api.example.com
- https://232.231.14.13
- http://232.231.14.13

to https://example.com, so I went with something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}



server {
    listen  443 ssl;

    if ($host != "example.com") {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /ssl/example.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/example.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
....
```