# Nginx not connecting url to application

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

This is my nginx site-enabled file.

```
server {

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name example.in;
    
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types application/javascript application/json text/css text/xml;
    gzip_comp_level 4;

    
location / {

        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    

     listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.in www.example.in;
    return 301 https://example.in$request_uri;
}
```

When I visit, example.in site is opening properly.
However when I open [www.example.in](http://www.example.in), I get default nginx page. What is wrong in this configuration? I have same configuration for other domain and that works fine.

nginx -T gives below results:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.in" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.in" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.in" on [::]:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.in" on [::]:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.in" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.in" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: Check your error log. It looks like you have a duplicate `server_name` listening on port 443.

Comment: @RichardSmith Is there a command for that? Can you rearrange and show answer for correct configuration? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view your entire configuration across all included files. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www/43089681#43089681) uses the default server to redirect everything to `example.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct. Check if there is any other nginx config file enabled under sites-enabled. Usually, a default file with the name 'default' is enabled with default server configuration, which can cause the problem. Check if that file also contains entry for [www.example.in](http://www.example.in). If that's the case disable it or make the file blank.