# Redirecting all non-www links to www using nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I’ve seen what some other posts do but replicating them doesn’t seem to work in my scenario. I’m trying to redirect all non-www links to www (specifically https-www), so if someone loads http://example.com or https://example.com, it'll redirect them to specifically https://www.example.com.

One post suggested a new server block as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80;
    server_name example.com

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

But this doesn’t redirect anything. Presumably this should apply when visiting http://example.com.

I also tried changing the http to https redirects generated by certbot - from this:

```
if ($host = www.example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

To this:

```
if ($host = www.example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri; # changed - added www
} # managed by Certbot
```

But this also didn’t work. I’d have thought adding `www.` before `$host` should prepend www to all http://example.com links, but this doesn't.

My full file (/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com (symlinked to /sites-enabled):

```
server {
    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Can anyone advise me what I’m doing wrong, and what would fix the non-www http and https redirects properly?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Still not working after being advised to follow the advice of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www/43089681#43089681) - I want to redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) from example.com but presumed the same principles apply. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43089681/4862445).

Comment: The first example already seems good, except that it does not redirect SSL traffic. This can make it hard to test the configuration, because browsers cache redirects and https can be forced (SNI), which would avoid the request completely. If you are on a Unix-like operating system try a command line tool like `wget -O- http://www.example.com/` to see what is going on (or restart your browser, but that does not help to avoid the second case)

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com    
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This should work... probably a stupid question, but have you restarted nginx since adding this to the config?

failing this, you could set up a redirection at dns level, from example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with a 301.

Answer (score 0):

Readed from this [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    ...
}
```