# nginx not redirecting www to https

Tags: nginx

I have a website which is properly handling all traffic and redirecting everything to https, except for www traffic. I followed [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www), but it didn't seem to fix it. This is my first time setting this up - any advice is appreciated. My goal is to redirect www.my_website.com to https://my_website.com, but currently it is redirecting to http://www.my_website.com

My DNS is set up as follows:

```
Type   | Name | Data         | Seconds
--------------------------------------
A      | @    | my_public_ip | Automatic
A      | www  | my_public_ip | Automatic
```

And my nginx is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    return 301 https://my_website.com;
}


# HTTPS server
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  my_website.com;

    ssl_certificate      some_random.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  some_random.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `nginx -T`

Comment: You may find this a useful reference: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/main/conf.d/templates/example.com.conf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx no-www to www and www to no-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947030/nginx-no-www-to-www-and-www-to-no-www)

Answer (score 1):

This is a schematic which applies for cases like this in general. It catches http and redirect to https, and redirects www to non-www. SSL-Certificates can be given separately (or the same for both), depending on Certificate.

```
server {
    # Handle http
    server_name www.my_website.com my_website.com;
    return 301 https://my_website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    # Handle www
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.my_website.com;
    ssl_certificate      some_random.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  some_random.key;
    return 301 https://my_website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  my_website.com;
    ssl_certificate      some_random.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  some_random.key;
    # your 'real' server
}
```

And it fixes this special problem here, because there is no rule for SSL www requests given. It would be possible to give `server_name  www.my_website.com my_website.com;` for SSL as well, if cert etc is valid for both.

Comment: Please explain your answer (note the change to the http server isn’t necessary :) )

Comment: Done, see edits

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out the issue, it was a small goof I made - I needed to change `server_name  my_website.com;` to `server_name  my_website.com, www.my_website.com;`

Comment: There is no redirect in the `server_name  my_website.com` server block - it's not clear how this is any part of a solution. Please edit the answer to clarify (and accept an answer so the question is considered resolved :)).