# How to access website deployed on Google cloud VM?

Tags: java, spring, networking, google-cloud-platform, web-hosting

I have a small Spring Boot application deployed on Google cloud VM. I have reserved a public IP for it. I have enabled DNS Zone, created A, CNAME records as well as I have put the provided google nameservers in GoDaddy DNS configuration. When I run `nslookup mywebsite.com` in the terminal. I am getting the correct IP address of the website. Also, the website is accessible through IP address. But I am unable to access it via domain name, i.e.

`http://IP_ADD:8080`: Works successfully.

`mywebsite.com`: Doesn't work. I get: `www.mywebsite.com` refused to connect.

The firewall rules in the google cloud VM instance are as follows:

[image: firewall rules]

Some of the articles which I have followed:
https://vinoaj.com/guides/2018/google-cloud-dns-for-godaddy-domain/

Also followed, google docs on the same topic. Which are also the same as the article.

Comment: Please, be aware that you are trying to access `www.mywebsite.com` while it seems you configured `mywebsite.com` in your DNS records. They are not the same thing. Probably you will need to configure a CNAME record for `www.mywebsite.com`. Consider, for example, this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566856/domain-ip-address-for-www-and-non-www-for-canonical-url), or [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www).  See next comment.

Comment: Also, pay attention in that you are accessing your web app on port 8080. do you have some kind of web server or service that redirects the traffic from port 80 and/or port 443 to the one in which your application is listening, 8080?

Comment: Hi @jccampanero I have already added CNAME record, I have also mentioned the same in the question. However, I agree with what you said about ports. Thank you. I will try out this.

Comment: That it is great @MSS, I am happy to hear that you managed to solve the problem. Just for future reference for people seeing the question, I will include an answer with the information.

Comment: OP, whenever you can, please mark @jccampanero 's  answer as correct if it solved the problem. This is good for SO, as next users could identify the solution to similar problems. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much @aran.

Answer (score 3):

Please, be aware that you are trying to access `www.mywebsite.com` while it seems you configured `mywebsite.com` in your DNS records. They are not the same thing.

Please, be sure that you configure a CNAME record for `www.mywebsite.com`. Consider, for example, this related SO question, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081780/dns-records-redirect-www-to-non-www) other one.

Also, pay attention in that you are accessing your web app on port 8080. You need some kind of web server, proxy, or service, like a load balancer, that redirects the traffic from port `80` and/or port `443` to the one in which your application is listening, `8080`.

---

*As another useful link, you could also check [***Google Cloud DNS Best Practices***](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/best-practices).*

Comment: Thank you very much for the contribution and the edit @aran, I really appreciate it.